# PHP passing variable to next page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm doing a review page where user will select the rating and write a review in a text area. I want to capture the userid of the user logged in, the imageid of the review given, the rating that user selected and text that the user entered . now the problem is that after clicking submit it would not redirect to my capture page .

```
window.location.href = "captcha.php?imageid='.$imageID.'&userid='.$userID.'&rating="+rating+"&text="+text";
```

this is the current code for javascript in php that redirect

```
<form name="form1" method="post" onSubmit = "return insertReview();">
```

this is the code for my form

Comment: add  the code for insertreview();

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function insertReview()
  {
   if (document.form1.userreview.value.length > 500)
{
alert ("Please use less than 500 words");
return false;
}
else
{ 
  var s = document.getElementById("rating");
  var rating = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;

  var textarea = document.getElementById("userreview").value;
  
 window.location.href = "captcha.php?imageid='.$imageID.'&userid='.$userID.'&rating="+rating+"&text="+text";
}
  }
  </script>

Comment: I think you can do this validation things in captcha.php, instead of doing this in javascript

Comment: do the words validationg in the captcha.php instead ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form name="form1" method="post" action = "captcha.php">
```

In captcha.php you can access the contents of form using the $_POST array.
Do  validation and filtering of data there. If something is wrong, give an error message and redirect to the previous page